# Use UPDATE in a loop

Tags: sql, ms-access, python-2.7, pyodbc

When I execute the following code:

```
for acc_row in cursor.execute("select * from tabela1"):
    cursor.execute("UPDATE table_name SET column_name=? where column_name=?", ('some_value','some_value'))
```

I receive the following error referencing the line containing the for loop:

```
ProgrammingError: No results. Previous SQL was not a query
```

The for loop works fine without the update statement, and vice versa

Software:

Python 2.7
Windows
pyodbc 3.0.7
AccessDatabaseEngine for MS Access 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are relying on the state of the `cursor.` object to control the `for` loop, but then you are modifying that object (by executing the UPDATE statement) inside the loop. You'll need to maintain two cursor objects, one to control the loop and another one to perform the UPDATEs.

Answer (score 1):

If your result set isn't large this should work:

```
rows = cursor.execute('select * from tabela1').fetchall()
for acc_row in rows:
    cursor.execute('UPDATE table_name SET column_name=? where column_name=?', (acc_row.column1, acc_row.column2))
```

If the result set is too large to load into memory, maintain two cursors as mentioned in Gord Thompson's answer.