# Python - Update SQL db success but no update in db has been made

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sql-update

I used update statement in a loop (Python) to update SQL database, the debug & execution did not show any error but when I checked SQL database, there is no change. Could you please point out where I did wrong? 
Here are some pieces of the code

```
query = """ select A from Table """ 
pyodbc.lowercase = False 
conn_str= (
          r'Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};'
          r'Server=MYLAPTOP;'
          r'Database=Access;'
          r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
          r'CHARSET=UTF8;'
        )

#open cursor 
crsr1 = cnxn.cursor() 
crsr2 = cnxn.cursor()

#Execute SQL to update 
crsr1.execute(query)
aList = [item[0] for item in crsr1.fetchall()] 
for row in crsr1.fetchall():
        crsr2.execute("""UPDATE Table SET A=(?) WHERE ID =(?)""", (row_list, row))
        cnxn.commit() 
crsr1.close() 
crsr2.close()
```

`row_list` contains rows of values which I want to use to update the rows in SQL database.
Based on [Use UPDATE in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18131329/11092824), I made 2 different cursors because the database is large but Im not sure if I did the right thing.

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Thanks!

**Edit:**
The purpose is to acquire the data (column A) from SQL which consists of rows of HEX values,

> (0xC209BF09BF09BA09B509B409B209B209B209B509BE09D209F2091A0A4A0A7D0AB40AE20A0A0B2A...)

which have `varbinary (max)` datatype in SQL. Then using programming at Python, I acquired the float conversion like this (for each row)

> 1999.0,1998.0,1998.0,2005.0,2021.0,2047.0,2077.0,2111.0,2145.0,2177.0,2205.0,2231.0,2253.0,2270.0,2285.0,2295.0,2301.0,......

Above is the float numbers of only one row. The `row_list` is the appended list of the values above, which contain many rows.

And the plan is to update the rows in SQL from `HEX to Float`. After getting it updated, I will convert SQL database into .txt. 
The ID is the order number from 1 to num of data (1,2,3...).

Comment: [Edit] your Question and explain in detail **what you want to accomplish**. **Why** dou have to *"UPDATE in a loop"*. Show the type of column `'ID'` *unique* or not. and show the output of `print(row_list)` as *"row_list contains rows of values"*.

Comment: I have a feeling this is because you iterate over the result of your SELECT query from `crsr1.execute(query)` twice. Try and replace `for row in crsr1.fetchall():` with `for row in aList:`.

Comment: @stovfl, I have edited the question and hopefully I didnt miss a thing

Comment: @shmee thank you, I just tried the advice, but unfortunately, it generates this error:

Comment: `pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type READONLY. (2715) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]...")`
I think it's because I updated the SQL with different data type

Comment: Not sure I follow. If your HEX values convert into sth like `1999.0,1998.0,1998.0,...`, then you don't have float values; you have a string consisting of comma separated elements that, individually, can be expressed as floats. It still is a string. You can't write that back into a column with datatype `varbinary`, as much as you can't write real floats to `varbinary`.

Comment: @Crn: Still missing  the type of column 'ID' unique or not. Assuming `ID` are unique, then it should look like  `WHERE ID =(?)""", (row_list, row.ID)` and using a **single** loop and cursor. But consider the comment from @shmee.